# Getting infoWindow open by default in Gmaps for rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

This is what I have for displaying the map with markers

```
<%= javascript_tag do%>
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'multi_markers'}}, function(){
    var markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
<%end%>
<% content_for :scripts do %>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
      if (Gmaps.map.markers.length == 1) {
        var marker = Gmaps.map.markers[0];
        var infowindow = marker.infowindow;
         infowindow.open(Gmaps.map.map, marker);
      }
    }
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Not exactly sure how should I be trying to have the infoWindows/markers open default on page load.

Thanks

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @apneadiving I am using 2.1.2 gmaps4rails

Comment: Why didnt you grant me the bounty? Be aware you wont get your points back anyway

Comment: @apneadiving sorry, I missed. I very much intended too. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution consists in triggering the `click` event on markers, then adjust map.

```
_.each(markers, function(marker){
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
});
```

[Here is a working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wlq5Dcv9Pmya4DhPVDwG?p=preview)

And remove the part with `Gmaps.map.callback`, its for 1.x